# Intellij icon in File Header

Tags: intellij-idea

What does the icon near file header represents in intelliJ IDE.
Please refer the image.[image]

Answer (score 2):

See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/symbols.html

That is a good overview, though I think that a couple of newer variations are missing.